# What's the difference between ./nuget.exe pack ./PartsUnlimited.Shared.csproj vs nuget pack ./PartsUnlimited.Shared.csproj on mac?

Tags: azure, macos, nuget

I am following a [lab](https://microsoftlearning.github.io/AZ400-DesigningandImplementingMicrosoftDevOpsSolutions/Instructions/Labs/AZ400_M08_L18_Package_Management_with_Azure_Artifacts.html) designed for visual studio on windows, on visual studio for mac.

The lab instructions are
`./nuget.exe pack ./PartsUnlimited.Shared.csproj` but it doesn't build anything and just pops open my finder to the folder where .csproj is in.

I had to do `nuget pack ./PartsUnlimited.Shared.csproj`  for it to build successfully.

What is the difference between these 2 commands?
Is it a shell/executable thing, or specific to nuget, or specific to macos?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the Windows OS, executable programs are expected to have a .exe file extension. With macOS and *nix operating systems, executable program do not have a special file extension.

When the lab instructions for Windows use `nuget.exe`, change it to `nuget` for macOS.

To specifically run the version of NuGet that you downloaded, `cd` to the directory that contains `nuget` and run the command as `./nuget`. (The lab is using the *nix directory separator in the examples.)